# How to tell valgrind to prepend the stack frames with the binary names (executable, shared lib)?

Tags: valgrind

I get:

```
==830==    at 0x4CD40DC: DebugSyslogHandlerFunc(DebugContext const&) (DebugSyslogHandler.cpp:202)
==830==    by 0x6A2F3: AssertHandler::~AssertHandler() (Debug.hpp:1219)
==830==    by 0x77F03: CircularQueue::capoffData(int) (CircularQueue.hpp:1216)
```

I want:

```
==830==    at 0x4CD40DC: /usr/local/lib/shared_lib1.so.0: DebugSyslogHandlerFunc(DebugContext const&) (DebugSyslogHandler.cpp:202)
==830==    by 0x6A2F3: /usr/local/lib/shared_lib2.so.0: AssertHandler::~AssertHandler() (Debug.hpp:1219)
==830==    by 0x77F03: /usr/local/bin/my_exe: CircularQueue::capoffData(int) (CircularQueue.hpp:1216)
```

(after every address there is the binary path and name).
I fail to find anything like that.

How to tell valgrind to prepend the stack frames with the binary names (executable, shared lib)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to instruct valgrind to always output the object name.
If valgrind finds the source location, then it does not output the object name.

The change to always output the object name is however trivial:

Adding the below marked lines (untested) in debuginfo.c should work

```
  if (know_srcloc) {
     if (know_objname) {   // Add from here
       APPEND(" (in ");    //
       APPEND(buf_obj);    //
       APPEND(")");        //
     }                     // Till here
     APPEND(" (");
```

Comment: I have tested this. Works perfect just as is. Thank you, phd!